# Turn ON/OFF WIFI with Flex Mobile/Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, air, wifi

I'm developing a Flex mobile app and to increase smartphone's battery duration I need to switch off wireless device and turn on when I need.

I only can find how to see status of WIFI connection, but I want disable WIFI.

Anyone know how to do this?

thks

Comment: There is no way to do this with Flex. With Air, you would need to create a Native Extension

Comment: @Eduardo Post that as a formal answer and I'll upvote it.  Honestly, I'm not sure I like the idea of an app being able to do this w/o user interaction.  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this with Flex. With Air, if at all doable (probably depends on the device's OS), you would need to create a Native Extension.